# How do I find the range,average and top three values from this list without a TypeError?

Tags: python, function, sorting, range, average

I m new to python and working on a small project:

90, 75, 65, 50, 40 are the grades below

My code:

```
grade1 = int(input("Enter grade 1:"))
grade2 = int(input("Enter grade 2:"))
grade3 = int(input("Enter grade 3:"))
grade4 = int(input("Enter grade 4:"))
grade5 = int(input("Enter grade 5:"))

numbers = [grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5]
sorted_grades = sorted(numbers)
topthree = sorted_grades[-1,-2,-3]
```

However, on running topthree I receive an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

How do I avoid this?

Comment: What you expecting from `sorted_grades[-1,-2,-3]`?

Comment: I am trying to get the top most grades. so in this example, I want 90,75,60 and it should drop the lowest two @Carcigenicate

Comment: It seems that you need to use negative indexing, e.g. `sorted_grades[-3: ]` or `sorted_grades[-3: ][::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use list slicing like so:

```
topthree = sorted_grades[:-4:-1]
```

I know it says `-4`, but it takes the top three.

If you want to use a list, it takes a bit more effort:

```
indices = [-1, -2, -3]
topthree = [sorted_grades[i] for i in indices]
```

You can also sort in reverse:

```
sorted_grades = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
topthree = sorted_grades[:3]
```

Comment: i used topthree = sorted_grades[:-4:-1] but how would I get the range and the average? range being largest number minus smallest in topthree

Comment: @user9991165 Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in the same question. Ask another one if needed; each question is for one specific problem. For both of your other issues, there are plenty of answers on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already collected the grades into a list called `grades`:

```
# New list of sorted entries
sorted_grades = sorted(grades)

# Sum of all list entries divided by the length
average = sum(grades)/len(grades)
# Last entry minus the first entry
range = grades[-1] - grades[0]
# Slice from the third-to-last entry to the end of the list
top_three = grades[-3:]
```

Syntax such as negative indexing and slicing is discussed further in the [tutorial provided in the CPython documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

> Like strings (and all other built-in sequence type), lists can be indexed and sliced:
>
> ```
> >>> squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
> >>> squares
> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
> >>> squares[0]  # indexing returns the item
> 1
> >>> squares[-1]
> 25
> >>> squares[-3:]  # slicing returns a new list
> [9, 16, 25]
> ```
>
> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements. This means that the following slice returns a new (shallow) copy of the list:
>
> ```
> >>> squares[:]
> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
> ```

The general format for list indexing/slicing is `some_list[start:stop:step]`:

```
>>> numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> numbers[0:3]  # slice from the first element to the third
[1, 3, 5]
>>> numbers[:3]  # 0's can be omitted
[1, 3, 5]
>>> numbers[1:3]  # slice from the second element to the third
[3, 5]
>>> numbers[3:]  # slice from the third element to the end
[7, 9]
>>> numbers[-3:]  # slice from the third-to-last to the end
[5, 7, 9]
>>> numbers[::-1]  # slice of the whole list, stepping backward by 1 for each entry
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
>>> numbers[1::2]  # slice of every other entry, starting with the second
[3, 7]
```

Note the list slices are end-exclusive, so `numbers[1:2]` only returns the second entry: `[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Python use `:` symbol for list slicing. So instead of use `topthree = sorted_grades[-1,-2,-3]`, use `topthree = sorted_grades[-1:-4:-1]`.
Format for list slicing is `[start:stop:step]`.